# Wanted: Cuckoo Hashing in C#

Tags: c#, .net, hash

I'm reading a lot of SO answers that talk about [Cuckoo hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing).

**Does anyone know a good implementation of Cuckoo in C#?**

Comment: Are you asking for a Homework?

Comment: Noop... just wanted to know if there is one. Why invent the wheel yourself. And I could imagine that there are more people out there that are looking for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would a minimum perfect hash that doesn't use the cuckoo algorithm work? If so, here's a C# implementation of the [CMPH Compress, Hash, and Displace](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/chd.html) algorithm:

[Laurent Dupuis's C# Compress, Hash, and Displace](http://www.dupuis.me/node/9)

You may prefer it over cuckoo hashing. From the [accompanying paper](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/papers/esa09.pdf):

> The main advantage of *k*-perfect
>   hashing is that it requires a single
>   random access to the slow memory in
>   the worst case. This is not the case
>   for other schemes like the linear
>   hashing method proposed by Litwin [15]
>   and the bucketed cuckoo hashing [9].

Comment: My testing shows Laurent Dupuis' implementation doesn't work above approx. 20,000 items. Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 2):

If you've found a C implementation, then it should be trivial to convert that to C#.....post the bits of the C implemenation that you are having problems converting...

Comment: Maybe not trivial, but reasonably straightforward.

Comment: I was converting a Java implementation, but I coudn't solve the generics stuff. But reading the amount of solutions that use this algorithm made me wonder if there already is a good C# implementation.